# Why Magento has name Magento but Not color is Magento?

Tags: magento2

Name always has history. what is the history of magento naming.

why Magento name used but color not used magento?

Comment: I thought it was Magenta that is color and Magento is a framework.

Comment: It because t-mobile disallow to others to be in magenta color, see https://www.engadget.com/2007/11/09/know-your-rights-does-t-mobile-really-own-magenta/